# Sorting on ip address fields using crossfilter

Tags: sorting, ip-address, crossfilter

I would like to know if there is any way to sort on ipaddress using crossfilter?

For example:
I have an array of ip's :

```
  [{ ip: "10.102.126.1"},{ ip: "10.102.126.2"},{ ip: "10.102.126.3"},{ ip: "10.102.126.4"},{ ip: "10.102.126.5"},{ ip: "10.102.126.6"},{ ip: "10.22.126.1"},{ ip: "20.102.126.1"},{ ip: "20.22.126.1"},{ ip: "100.22.126.1"},{ ip: "200.22.126.1"}]
```

When I apply crossfilter and get the using:

> `dimension.top(Infinity)`

It does the string sort and return.

Output: *200.22.126.1 , 20.22.126.1 , 20.102.126.1 , 100.22.126.1 , 10.22.126.1 , 10.102.126.6 , 10.102.126.5 , 10.102.126.4 , 10.102.126.3 , 10.102.126.2 , 10.102.126.1*

Now here how can I perform IP Address sort?

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nbh34a8g/1/)

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code inline in the question and point out specifically what the problem is. The short answer to your question is "yes". The issue is how.

Comment: My bad. I did not used stack-overflow much before. I have edited my question.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but I think it's going to be simplest to sort by a number consisting of the whole IP address.

Since JavaScript doesn't really have integers (only floats), let's instead sort by the zero-padded hexadecimal representation of the number. [It should be safe to deal with numbers up to 2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin), but it just feels risky to me. Strings are more straightforward.

Note that you can apply whatever transformation you want to produce the dimension key, so even something crazy like this should work:

```
function ip_to_hex(s) {
  return s.split('.').map(i=>(+i).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
}
var cf = crossfilter(data),
    dim = cf.dimension(d => ip_to_hex(d.ip));
```

What? Yes:

1. split by dots
2. convert each part to a number
3. convert each part to a base-16 string
4. make sure each part has two digits
5. sew them all back up with no separator

Now the keys are strings like `"02167e01"` and crossfilter will sort them correctly (`.top()` sorts from highest to lowest):

```
[
  {
    "ip": "200.22.126.1"
  },
  {
    "ip": "100.22.126.1"
  },
  {
    "ip": "20.102.126.1"
  },
  {
    "ip": "20.22.126.1"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.102.126.6"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.102.126.5"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.102.126.4"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.102.126.3"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.102.126.2"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.102.126.1"
  },
  {
    "ip": "10.22.126.1"
  }
]
```

[Demo fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lp89xea2/)